# Is it possible to check that a condition holds true continuously for a certain duration before executing a set of code? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, benchmarking

For example, let's say that some variable changes based on user input. When this variable reaches some condition, it must hold that condition for some set time before some other code is executed.

```
if(changingVariable == someValue for some amount of time){
    //code to be executed
}
```

**NOTE:** I want the answer to be as general as possible so that it can be applied to any situation.

For some context, here is the situation that I will be using it in:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (CMMotionManager *)motionManager {
    _motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    _motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1;
    return _motionManager;
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self isStable];
}

- (void)isStable {
    if(!self.motionManager.isAccelerometerActive) {
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accData, NSError *error){
                CGFloat x = accData.acceleration.x;
                CGFloat y = accData.acceleration.y;
                //CGFloat z = accData.acceleration.z;           
        }];

        // This is the condition that needs to hold true 
        // for half of a second before executing some code 
        if(fabs(x) < .095 && fabs(y) < .095){
            // Code that takes a picture
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Edit: I just want to say thanks to all who helped!

Comment: Assuming you don't want to adopt some framework such as react that is event-driven and can do this sort of thing for you, you will need to take a timestamp when the first update is received and keep track of the elapsed time in subsequent updates.  If the condition is not met then clear the start time and wait for the condition to be met again.  If the condition is still met and the appropriate time has passed then carry on.

Comment: The question is somewhat vague. Do you want the condition to hold true throughout the 0.5 seconds for all accelerometer update frames or just want the condition to evaluate true before the 0.5 sec interval starts and before the interval ends?

Comment: @AyanSengupta I want it to hold true throughout the .5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being unaware of your real intention, I'm proposing a bridged solutions covering up the scenarios.

First declare `x` and `y` as class properties

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat x;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat y;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL scheduled;
...
```

Next modify your motion manager update code like this

```
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accData, NSError *error){
    self.x = accData.acceleration.x;
    self.y = accData.acceleration.y;

    // This is the condition that needs to hold true
    // for half of a second before executing some code
    if(fabs(self.x) < .095 && fabs(self.y) < .095) {
        //schedule your takePicture routine to be executed after 0.5 seconds
        //if not already scheduled
        if (!self.scheduled) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
            self.scheduled = YES;
        }
    }
    /*
    else {
        //cancel previously scheduled method 
        //if the condition doesn't hold true in an intermediate update
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(takePicture) object:nil];

        //reset the flag so that further scheduling is possible
        self.scheduled = NO;
    }
    */
}];
```

And now in your `takePicture` routine reevaluate the condition and execute code only if the condition is true:

```
-(void)takePicture {
    if (fabs(self.x) < .095 && fabs(self.y) < .095) {
        // Code that takes a picture
    }

    //reset the flag so that further scheduling is possible
    self.scheduled = NO;
}
```

So to summarize things:

1. We capture accelerometer updates for each frame.
2. Schedule a `takePicture` routine after 0.5 seconds
3. In the `takePicture` routine reevaluate the condition and if it still holds
   true we execute capture code.

So what's left? Here we have considered only the terminal conditions -- we evaluated the condition just before 0.5 seconds interval commences and just after it ends. But it doesn't guarantee the condition holds `true` in between. If we also need to conform to this scenario, we need to cancel the previously scheduled routine if the condition deviates from its `true` state and that can be achieved by uncommenting the `else` block in motion manager update portion that I've commented out for the time being.

Comment: @ss_thebeast Unfortunately the given reply is somewhat faulty! Imagine the situation when the condition evaluated `true` for the first time and the code have scheduled the `takePicture` routine once. Now a next accelerometer update arrives and if the condition still holds `true` the code will schedule the routine once more. That is certainly not something we have expected. The situation can easily be mitigated by using a flag property and I have updated my answer accordingly. The property is named as `scheduled` in my updated answer.